# Laravel Notifications failing when unserialize

Tags: php, laravel

On my forge production server, I have configured Laravel 5.3 notifications, and all of the notifications use the `Illuminate\Bus\Queueable` trait and implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` interface. This is done in a `App\Notifications\BaseNotification` class that I created and all of my notifications classes extends.

I also have a worker configured to run the queue.

Everything always gone OK, but this night I started receiving this error when executing a notification:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager::sendNow(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "CenaZero\Notifications\Orders\OrderCompletedOwnerNotification" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition 
in /home/forge/cenazero.com.br/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php:64
```

The code from the class reported on error is the following:

```
<?php

namespace CenaZero\Notifications\Orders;

use CenaZero\Models\Order;
use CenaZero\Notifications\BaseNotification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use NotificationChannels\Gcm\GcmMessage;
use NotificationChannels\Zenvia\ZenviaMessage;

class OrderCompletedProducerNotification extends BaseNotification
{
    private $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $data = [
            'order'    => $this->order,
            'item'     => $this->order->item,
            'product'  => $this->order->item->product,
            'producer' => $notifiable,
            'to'       => $notifiable->email,
        ];

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->view(['emails.orders.completed.producer', 'emails.orders.completed.producer-plain'], $data)
            ->subject($this->translation('subject'));
    }

    public function toZenvia($notifiable)
    {
        return ZenviaMessage::create()
                ->content($this->translation('message'))
                ->id('order-completed-producer-' . $this->order->id);
    }

    public function toGcm($notifiable)
    {
        return GcmMessage::create()
            ->title($this->translation('title'))
            ->message($this->translation('message'));
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->order->id,
            'status_id'   => $this->order->status_id,
            'message'     => $this->translation('title'),
            'description' => $this->translation('message'),
        ];
    }
}
```

**Obs:** The `via` method is defined in the `BaseNotification` class, and the `translation` method is just a helper to get the message from lang files.

I don't know for sure if it's a framework problem, maybe there's a problem when Laravel try to unserializing  my job. But I don't know how I can discover that or how can I handle this.

When I execute the same workflow on my local machine (also using queues) work's correctly.

Can you guys help me somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This part from the given error message,

```
...Please ensure that the class definition 
"CenaZero\Notifications\Orders\OrderCompletedOwnerNotification" 
of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded...
```

shows that the class wasn't autoloaded.

Add the base folder containing the classes used under `CenaZero` namespace to the array of [mapped namespaces in composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload). That way classes under the namespace are autoloaded before a script attempts deserialize an object using them.

**composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CenaZero\\": "<relative-path-to-root-folder-of-namespace>/",
        }
    }
}
```